# Use daplink with stm32

Tags: stm32, keil, st-link

I bought CMSIS daplink with stm32f103c8 blue pill, and I'm using Keil microvision for programming stm32, when I try to download code to stm32, program shows error "no st link detected", can I fix this?

Comment: CMSIS-DAP isn't the same thing as ST-Link.  You have selected the wrong driver.

Comment: how can I change it?, if I go to Options and execute change in Debug mode from ST-LINK to CMSIS-Dap debugger I got error "Not a geniune ST device"

Comment: It sounds like you have bought a counterfeit device.  It will not work.  You need to buy a genuine device from a reputable supplier.  Sorry.

Comment: I would suspect you need to change the debugging device, it probably expects an ST-Link, not a DAPlink

Comment: Daplink can program other devices as well, use openOCD and change the expected signature.